# Uncompress docx files, compare their contents and create a new merged docx file

Tags: c#, zip, comparison, ms-office, docx

Why docx re-compressed with `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` is not identical to original one?

I'm building a module for "docx" (and other word documents) comparison. First of all I uncompress two "docx" files. Then I compare and merge the xml files in directory structure that have been created after documents' decompression. In the end I compress the merged directory and create the new "docx" file. The two "docx" files (the original one and the merged one) are same according to Microsoft word comparison. Also the xml contents are same according to CRC32 comparison, but either size or CRC32 value of the merged "docx" file are different from the original one. For the decompression I use the 
System.IO.Compression library.

Is this a compression problem? What is the compression algorithm that the microsoft word (and other viewers use) for creating open xml format documents such as "docx" files?

I run some unit tets for several docx comparisons. So i think the only way to check if a test passed correctly is to compare the crc32 numbers.

```
 public static void CreateCompressFile(string dirinfo, string originalFile)
 {
     FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(originalFile);
     ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(dirinfo, 
         originalFile.Replace(fi.Extension, "_tmp" + fi.Extension),
         CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
 }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what problem you have? (docx is indeed ZIP - you can find all details in official documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd773189(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: After **uncompress** and then **recompress** a merged document the crc32 value is diferrent but the docx file is the same with the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Docx is ZIP file. As long as de-compressed content is the same files can be considered identical from Word's point of view (unless you need to sign ZIP file itself for some reason).

ZIP file format does not require some particular format for compressed data - it explicitly allows variations on compression quality. Each compression library/tool is free to pick compression level based on its internal criteria. It is unlikely that 2 different implementations will produce identical ZIP files from the same content even if options passed to compression as similar.

I.e. even sample you have shows ability to pick [CompressionLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.compressionlevel(v=vs.110).aspx): `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(...,CompressionLevel.Fastest, ...);`.

Similar questions discussed before on SE: [ZIP files created with GUI have more bytes than ZIP files created in a shell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194872/zip-files-created-with-gui-have-more-bytes-than-zip-files-created-in-a-shell).